# supportedInterfaceOrientations not being called in plus size devices

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

There are several similar questions in SO regarding orientation changes not taking place, but none of them seemingly address the issue here.

Specifically, I am rotating a view to landscape using 
*supportedInterfaceOrientations* and *preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation*, but the overrides are not getting called for me in **plus size** phones. Every other device is fine, but not so in a 6+ and 7+ device.

Is there a logical reason why this may be so? *shouldAutorotate* is returning true, so in theory everything should be OK.

Comment: did you make your class as a subclass for UINavigationController

Comment: No UIViewController. Is there a reason why you think this would have an impact on plus size phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that forcing rotation when simultaneously using a modalPresentationStyle does not work in the plus size phones. Removing this presentation method has corrected the issue for me.